# Shell script Sed - How to read a file and write in another file only in the first occurrence of a string?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

I am trying to read the content of the file test.txt  and write in another file Report.html, only in the first match of a string. Something like:

```
sed -i '/, past/r test.txt' Report.html
```

This command above is reading all strings ", past" and including the content of the test.txt in all strings ", past". But I just want that includes in the first occurrence of the string ", past". A command like:

```
sed -i '0,/, past/r test.txt' Report.html
```

The command above is not working, what's the correct syntax for that?

Comment: `'0,/, past/r test.txt'` works with gnu-sed

Comment: Doesn't work for me, under cygwin. No output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the sed `r` command does not take range, and sed control does not otherwise allow "first only", I think you need to "calculate" the line number of interest and feed that to sed:

```
sed -i $(awk '/, past/{print NR;exit}' Report.html)'r test.txt' Report.html
```

Only do this if you're *guaranteed* that `, past` occurs in Report.html somewhere. If not, store the `$(awk...)` result in a variable and check it first. Otherwise the `sed` will do the include for *every* line.